# How to add a row in HTML tables when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I want to add a record in a dynamic table which can be a datatables/ html tables when submitting the record values in a HTML form (*Not a jquery dialog).Similar for Editing row values.

Editor Datatables plugin [link](https://editor.datatables.net/) having the same UI dev but its not a freeware plugin.

Note: Using any new technologies like Datatables,Bootstrap,html5,jquery and javascript open src plugins for a better UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Jquery Grid Plugins. If they are satisfied with your requirements  use them. They are free  http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/enhance-tables-functional-jquery-plugins/

Comment: NO those are all for Inline editing tables. My requirement is to use  normal html form submit and tables.any other suggestion.

Comment: Note : form can be a twitter bootstrap model dialog.Any help ?